# Reading content of table with column name as value

Tags: sqlite, case

after years of reading, I now have a question, that I did'nt find, probably because I don't really know how it's called what I want.

I recentyl started using databases and sql and therefore I have a minimum of knowledge about it.
What I need is the following:

I want an output that looks like this:

```
Post Code | coordinates | Birth Date | Temperature
```

The first three come from different Tables, everything fine. Bute the last one is the tricky one: 
My Temperature table (temperature) looks like this:

```
Date | 50.95N_12.45E |50.85N_12.35E |...
1.1.1950|10|3.2|...
2.1.1950|10.2|3.5|...
```

And now I need to tell sqlite:

```
SELECT mom.coordinates AS coordniates

temperature.(what you find in coordinates) AS temperature

FROM...
```

Is this understandable?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't refer to a column's name like that.
You must enumerate all the columns in a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT mom.coordinates AS coordniates,
CASE mom.coordinates
  WHEN '50.95N_12.45E' THEN temperature."50.95N_12.45E"
  WHEN '50.85N_12.35E' THEN temperature."50.85N_12.35E"
  ................................. 
END AS temperature
FROM
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, will be much writing, but if it works its fine :)

Comment: So, I now, its quite some time, but I'm still not rreally where I need to be. And I think I put the question wrong or at least not entirely right.

Comment: I need to search for the temperature that was recorded on the birthdate and on every date before that for 5 days. So I have to add something, that is checking for the date in my temperature table. In Excel I now, that I can use a combination of index and match and this is how i've done it so far, but this is really annoying, because I have to build the .sql, export it to .csv and edti it with Excel, and if something happened, that I see was wrong, I start all over... :(

Comment: @Mitu What you describe in your comment has nothing to do with your question. My answer is about the question as you posted it. If you have anew requirement then you can ask a new question where you explain what you want and not unaccept my answer..